# valid definition of complex geodesic

Tags: complex-geometry, geodesic

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, and let $Y$ be a complex submanifold of $X$.

If $X$ has an hermitian structure(on its tangent bundle), we can consider the Chern connection $\nabla$ on the holomorphic tangent bundle $\mathcal{T}_X$ which is compatible with the hermitian structure.

Then, for $Y$, is it possible to define the second fundamental form with respect to the connection and the hermitian structure?

Also, is it available to say that $Y$ is *totally geodesic* if its second fundamental form vanishes on $Y$?

I have googled about this thing, but it is hard to find any reference.

One that I am studying is 'Complex Geometry' of Huybrechts. On page 175, there is a definition of the second fundamental form.

It seems possible to define those things, but I am not sure of it, and also I am wondering that is it a useful definition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, such definitions certainly make sense: If $\nabla$ is a metric connection, and if $U$ and $V$ are tangent to $Y$, then $\nabla_{U} V$ may be decomposed using the metric into a component tangent to $Y$ and a component normal to $Y$; the latter is the second fundamental form $\operatorname{II}(U, V)$. That is, you're treating the metric as a Riemannian metric, and the Chern connection as the Levi-Civita connection.